# Why is my Flutter app crashing on app quit?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, crash, ios-simulator

When testing in iOS Simulator (via xCode) if I quit the app, it'll crash with the following message in the console.

`Runner[8634:2415656] No windows have a root view controller, cannot save application state. Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`

When testing this on TestFlight with a real device I'll get the iOS popup asking to share the crash with the developer.

When testing in iOS Simulator (via Android Studio) if I quit the app, it'll crash with the following report.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 4A2DB6C2-E514-426A-AC63-FD84E86DDB60
CrashReporter Key:   BC9E8BD4-1F8E-B01D-EB15-55886F049B8D
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro17,1
Process:             Runner [5846]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E866506-13AF-4DC7-A85B-9484B500F293/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F34F60DC-D13B-4711-A6EE-9B5758B0D744/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.test.calculator
Version:             4.0.0 (2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [3390]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.1E866506-13AF-4DC7-A85B-9484B500F293 [6654]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [11148]

Date/Time:           2022-01-13 07:07:09.9905 -0500
Launch Time:         2022-01-13 07:07:02.2121 -0500
OS Version:          macOS 12.1 (21C52)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000006f0
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000000006f0
VM Region Info: 0x6f0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4377901328
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                      104f18000-104f1c000    [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...er.app/Runner
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [5846]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 783.5 - Device: iPhone 13 (1E866506-13AF-4DC7-A85B-9484B500F293) - Runtime: iOS 15.2 (19C51) - DeviceType: iPhone 13
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   Flutter                                0x107d04784 flutter::Engine::GetWeakPtr() const + 0
1   Flutter                                0x107d11f98 flutter::Shell::OnPlatformViewSetSemanticsEnabled(bool) + 72
2   Flutter                                0x10792ac90 flutter::PlatformViewIOS::AccessibilityBridgePtr::~AccessibilityBridgePtr() + 56
3   Flutter                                0x10792b1a4 flutter::PlatformViewIOS::~PlatformViewIOS() + 104
4   Flutter                                0x10792b20c flutter::PlatformViewIOS::~PlatformViewIOS() + 12
5   Flutter                                0x107d18f30 std::__1::__function::__func<fml::internal::CopyableLambda<flutter::Shell::~Shell()::$_6>, std::__1::allocator<fml::internal::CopyableLambda<flutter::Shell::~Shell()::$_6> >, void ()>::operator()() + 40
6   Flutter                                0x107d10154 flutter::Shell::~Shell() + 1020
7   Flutter                                0x1078f6a94 std::__1::unique_ptr<flutter::Shell, std::__1::default_delete<flutter::Shell> >::reset(flutter::Shell*) + 28
8   Flutter                                0x1078f69c8 -[FlutterEngine destroyContext] + 60
9   CoreFoundation                         0x180321404 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
10  CoreFoundation                         0x1803213bc ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 48
11  CoreFoundation                         0x1803207e0 _CFXRegistrationPost + 416
12  CoreFoundation                         0x1803201c8 _CFXNotificationPost + 680
13  Foundation                             0x1807c442c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92
14  UIKitCore                              0x184d9e518 -[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 168
15  UIKitCore                              0x1843bbcac -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 124
16  UIKitCore                              0x1843bb990 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer forceExitWithTransitionContext:scene:] + 220
17  UIKitCore                              0x184d94b64 -[UIApplication workspaceShouldExit:withTransitionContext:] + 180
18  FrontBoardServices                     0x186177178 __63-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient willTerminateWithTransitionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 76
19  FrontBoardServices                     0x18615a160 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 232
20  FrontBoardServices                     0x186177114 __63-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient willTerminateWithTransitionContext:]_block_invoke + 104
21  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18010a5a4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
22  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18010ddb0 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 244
23  FrontBoardServices                     0x18619d9a0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
24  FrontBoardServices                     0x18619d878 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 176
25  FrontBoardServices                     0x18619d9d0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 24
26  CoreFoundation                         0x1803502c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
27  CoreFoundation                         0x1803501c8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 200
28  CoreFoundation                         0x18034f554 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256
29  CoreFoundation                         0x180349b9c __CFRunLoopRun + 744
30  CoreFoundation                         0x1803493a8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
31  GraphicsServices                       0x18c03c5ec GSEventRunModal + 160
32  UIKitCore                              0x184d937ac -[UIApplication _run] + 992
33  UIKitCore                              0x184d982e8 UIApplicationMain + 112
34  Runner                                 0x104f1af24 main + 64 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
35  dyld_sim                               0x105139ca0 start_sim + 20
36  dyld                                   0x1052110f4 start + 520

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9884 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9884 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c9975050 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99753f0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                         0x18034f810 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368
3   CoreFoundation                         0x180349d24 __CFRunLoopRun + 1136
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1803493a8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Foundation                             0x180811e14 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                             0x1808120cc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   UIKitCore                              0x184e47b64 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 472
8   Foundation                             0x18083b97c __NSThread__start__ + 788
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9884 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:: io.flutter.1.ui
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c9975050 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99753f0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                         0x18034f810 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368
3   CoreFoundation                         0x180349d24 __CFRunLoopRun + 1136
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1803493a8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Flutter                                0x107c2cc44 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 88
6   Flutter                                0x107c25eac fml::MessageLoopImpl::DoRun() + 40
7   Flutter                                0x107c2b5bc void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::Thread::Thread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)::$_0> >(void*) + 192
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:: io.flutter.1.raster
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c9975050 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99753f0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                         0x18034f810 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368
3   CoreFoundation                         0x180349d24 __CFRunLoopRun + 1136
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1803493a8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Flutter                                0x107c2cc44 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 88
6   Flutter                                0x107c25eac fml::MessageLoopImpl::DoRun() + 40
7   Flutter                                0x107c2b5bc void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::Thread::Thread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)::$_0> >(void*) + 192
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:: io.flutter.1.io
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c9975050 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99753f0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                         0x18034f810 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368
3   CoreFoundation                         0x180349d24 __CFRunLoopRun + 1136
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1803493a8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Flutter                                0x107c2cc44 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 88
6   Flutter                                0x107c25eac fml::MessageLoopImpl::DoRun() + 40
7   Flutter                                0x107c2b5bc void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::Thread::Thread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)::$_0> >(void*) + 192
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 8:: io.flutter.1.profiler
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c9975050 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99753f0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                         0x18034f810 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368
3   CoreFoundation                         0x180349d24 __CFRunLoopRun + 1136
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1803493a8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Flutter                                0x107c2cc44 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 88
6   Flutter                                0x107c25eac fml::MessageLoopImpl::DoRun() + 40
7   Flutter                                0x107c2b5bc void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::Thread::Thread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)::$_0> >(void*) + 192
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 9:: io.worker.1
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec44 _pthread_cond_wait + 1216
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x180255cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   Flutter                                0x107c2302c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 156
4   Flutter                                0x107c2361c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0> >(void*) + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 10:: io.worker.2
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec44 _pthread_cond_wait + 1216
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x180255cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   Flutter                                0x107c2302c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 156
4   Flutter                                0x107c2361c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0> >(void*) + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 11:: io.worker.3
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec44 _pthread_cond_wait + 1216
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x180255cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   Flutter                                0x107c2302c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 156
4   Flutter                                0x107c2361c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0> >(void*) + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 12:: io.worker.4
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec44 _pthread_cond_wait + 1216
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x180255cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   Flutter                                0x107c2302c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 156
4   Flutter                                0x107c2361c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0> >(void*) + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 13:: io.worker.5
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec44 _pthread_cond_wait + 1216
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x180255cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   Flutter                                0x107c2302c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 156
4   Flutter                                0x107c2361c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0> >(void*) + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 14:: io.worker.6
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec44 _pthread_cond_wait + 1216
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x180255cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   Flutter                                0x107c2302c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 156
4   Flutter                                0x107c2361c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0> >(void*) + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 15:: io.worker.7
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec44 _pthread_cond_wait + 1216
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x180255cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   Flutter                                0x107c2302c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 156
4   Flutter                                0x107c2361c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0> >(void*) + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 16:: io.worker.8
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec44 _pthread_cond_wait + 1216
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x180255cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   Flutter                                0x107c2302c fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 156
4   Flutter                                0x107c2361c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0> >(void*) + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 17:: dart:io EventHandler
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c997aa64 kevent + 8
1   Flutter                                0x107e1cfd4 dart::bin::EventHandlerImplementation::EventHandlerEntry(unsigned long) + 328
2   Flutter                                0x107e3b64c dart::bin::ThreadStart(void*) + 48
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 18:: DartWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec70 _pthread_cond_wait + 1260
2   Flutter                                0x107f6d80c dart::Monitor::WaitMicros(long long) + 128
3   Flutter                                0x107fe4c50 dart::ThreadPool::WorkerLoop(dart::ThreadPool::Worker*) + 436
4   Flutter                                0x107fe4f18 dart::ThreadPool::Worker::Main(unsigned long) + 100
5   Flutter                                0x107f6ced0 dart::ThreadStart(void*) + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 19:: DartWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec70 _pthread_cond_wait + 1260
2   Flutter                                0x107f6d80c dart::Monitor::WaitMicros(long long) + 128
3   Flutter                                0x107fe4c50 dart::ThreadPool::WorkerLoop(dart::ThreadPool::Worker*) + 436
4   Flutter                                0x107fe4f18 dart::ThreadPool::Worker::Main(unsigned long) + 100
5   Flutter                                0x107f6ced0 dart::ThreadStart(void*) + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 20:: DartWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec70 _pthread_cond_wait + 1260
2   Flutter                                0x107f6d80c dart::Monitor::WaitMicros(long long) + 128
3   Flutter                                0x107fe4c50 dart::ThreadPool::WorkerLoop(dart::ThreadPool::Worker*) + 436
4   Flutter                                0x107fe4f18 dart::ThreadPool::Worker::Main(unsigned long) + 100
5   Flutter                                0x107f6ced0 dart::ThreadStart(void*) + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 21:: DartWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec70 _pthread_cond_wait + 1260
2   Flutter                                0x107f6d80c dart::Monitor::WaitMicros(long long) + 128
3   Flutter                                0x107fe4c50 dart::ThreadPool::WorkerLoop(dart::ThreadPool::Worker*) + 436
4   Flutter                                0x107fe4f18 dart::ThreadPool::Worker::Main(unsigned long) + 100
5   Flutter                                0x107f6ced0 dart::ThreadStart(void*) + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8

Thread 22:: DartWorker
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1c99784c4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99cec70 _pthread_cond_wait + 1260
2   Flutter                                0x107f6d80c dart::Monitor::WaitMicros(long long) + 128
3   Flutter                                0x107eb0260 dart::MutatorThreadPool::OnEnterIdleLocked(dart::MonitorLocker*) + 196
4   Flutter                                0x107fe4c90 dart::ThreadPool::WorkerLoop(dart::ThreadPool::Worker*) + 500
5   Flutter                                0x107fe4f18 dart::ThreadPool::Worker::Main(unsigned long) + 100
6   Flutter                                0x107f6ced0 dart::ThreadStart(void*) + 168
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99ce68c _pthread_start + 116
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1c99c9898 thread_start + 8


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000107d11f50   x3: 0x000000018015a66c
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000600000d11e60   x6: 0x0000000000000010   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x000000016aee4078   x9: 0x0000000000000001  x10: 0x00000000000007fd  x11: 0x0000000000000001
   x12: 0x00000000000000a3  x13: 0x0000000005e5008c  x14: 0x0000000006050800  x15: 0x0000000000050800
   x16: 0x00000001801913d0  x17: 0x000000018018fe38  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x000000012981ce00  x21: 0x0000600000399840  x22: 0x0000000129523260  x23: 0x000000016aee41d8
   x24: 0x000000016aee42c8  x25: 0x0000600000d10030  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000006d00000066
   x28: 0x0000000000001c00   fp: 0x000000016aee40f0   lr: 0x0000000107d11f98
    sp: 0x000000016aee4070   pc: 0x0000000107d04784 cpsr: 0x80001000
   far: 0x00000000000006f0  esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
       0x1078ec000 -        0x109357fff io.flutter.flutter (1.0) <55c8675f-1ff8-3499-9403-360bb5c0ece7> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E866506-13AF-4DC7-A85B-9484B500F293/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F34F60DC-D13B-4711-A6EE-9B5758B0D744/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter
       0x1802cb000 -        0x180677fff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <3b05273d-3bbf-321d-8274-b848d167fd37> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x1806eb000 -        0x1809acfff com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <19f16173-af39-3bfe-aef4-ec9cb4d4ffa0> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x184189000 -        0x185613fff com.apple.UIKitCore (1.0) <08a5560d-3f2b-3b52-a202-add2a39b5d30> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x186142000 -        0x1861cbfff com.apple.FrontBoardServices (764.7) <62073d39-df33-35ac-abc7-d22898e945e7> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
       0x180107000 -        0x180149fff libdispatch.dylib (*) <00a1d5e5-18c3-3ff6-b4b1-34e1d3856727> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x18c039000 -        0x18c041fff com.apple.GraphicsServices (1.0) <01858b6b-f559-3623-9aaf-d03b35fccf3c> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x104f18000 -        0x104f1bfff com.test.calculator (4.0.0) <e9eb7b84-1b9e-3628-80e8-c9627cd3fa29> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E866506-13AF-4DC7-A85B-9484B500F293/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F34F60DC-D13B-4711-A6EE-9B5758B0D744/Runner.app/Runner
       0x105138000 -        0x105173fff dyld_sim (*) <4f051b2d-f44f-31d5-8c60-061d25c5d57e> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim
       0x10520c000 -        0x10526bfff dyld (*) <7e92b284-4b90-3b68-b31a-3ddc4c0e8d40> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1c99c7000 -        0x1c99d3fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <0c35ca59-6c83-3758-966f-c69972e2cee8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x1c9974000 -        0x1c99a7fff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <d8ee1410-83fd-3820-b402-f978c539bd03> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x180249000 -        0x1802a5fff libc++.1.dylib (*) <0b16a27c-16a3-3281-9baf-04cf060e5d79> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???

EOF

-----------
... there is more but I've hit the character limit.
-----------
```

If I run `flutter run --verbose`, at the point of crash, it reports this in the console:

```
[        ] Lost connection to device.
[   +3 ms] DevFS: Deleting filesystem on the device
(file:///Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1E866506-13AF-
4DC7-A85B-9484B500F293/data/Containers/Data/Application/8C184006-767C-43A4-8189-
1EE2DA46F6AB/tmp/calcappcQPKkx/calcapp/)
[ +258 ms] Ignored error while cleaning up DevFS: TimeoutException after
0:00:00.250000: Future not completed
[  +27 ms] "flutter run" took 75,376ms.
[  +12 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 0
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.9.0-1.0.pre.343, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm,
    locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    31.0.0-rc3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    ! Error: J iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when
      J iPhone is connected. (code -13)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

What other info can I provide that'll be helpful?
What should I try to do to resolve the issue?

Comment: This seems to have resolved itself somehow after all the googling and experiments.
Not sure what kicked it in the pants.

Comment: How did you fixed that? We are facing the same issue. @benny

Comment: @esha I'm not sure what solved.